# Why does not get_field() in WordPress work when I transfer the code to template part

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting mad
I had those variables

```
$wwa_section_title = get_field('wwa_section_title');
$wwa_section_description  = get_field('wwa_section_description');
$wwa_section_body = get_field('wwa_section_body');
$wwa_section_image_1       = get_field('wwa_section_image_1');
$wwa_section_image_2       = get_field('wwa_section_image_2')
```

And this is the HTML section

```
<div class="container-fluid about-company">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 hero-title text-center">
                    <h2 class="text-capitalize">
                        <?php 
                       echo $wwa_section_title;
                    ?>
                    </h2>
                    <p class="hero-paragraph">
                        <?php
                        echo $wwa_section_body;
                    ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
                        <img src="<?php echo $wwa_section_image_2['url'];?>" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <img src="<?php echo $wwa_section_image_1['url'];?>" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
                        <p class="about-paragraph small">
                            <?php
                        echo $wwa_section_description;
                    ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-4">
                        <ul class="about-us-list">
                            <li class="about-us-list-item">
                                <div class="about-list-item-check">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-checked"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="about-list-item-text">Ipsum is simply text of the stry simply</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="about-us-list-item">
                                <div class="about-list-item-check">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-checked"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="about-list-item-text">Dummy text of the print</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="about-us-list-item">
                                <div class="about-list-item-check">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-checked"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="about-list-item-text">Ipsum is simply text of the stry simply</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="about-us-list-item">
                                <div class="about-list-item-check">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-checked"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="about-list-item-text">Dummy text of the print</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="about-us-list-item">
                                <div class="about-list-item-check">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-checked"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="about-list-item-text">Ipsum is simply text of the stry simply</div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <ul class="about-us-list">
                            <li class="about-us-list-item">
                                <div class="about-list-item-check">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-checked"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="about-list-item-text">Ipsum is simply text of the stry simply</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="about-us-list-item">
                                <div class="about-list-item-check">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-checked"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="about-list-item-text">Dummy text of the print</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="about-us-list-item">
                                <div class="about-list-item-check">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-checked"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="about-list-item-text">Ipsum is simply text of the stry simply</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="about-us-list-item">
                                <div class="about-list-item-check">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-checked"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="about-list-item-text">Dummy text of the print</div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="about-us-list-item">
                                <div class="about-list-item-check">
                                    <i class="icofont icofont-checked"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="about-list-item-text">Ipsum is simply text of the stry simply</div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

When I transfer this code into a template part and try to render it, the variables become empty.
Once I role back and return the whole code into the page template it wotks fine

I tried to use `$post->ID` and did not work
I tried to use `the_field()` instead and did not work

Answer (score 0):

You don't explain at which place in your code you initialize your variables, so I can just guess what might be the problem.

The [`get_field`](http://hookr.io/functions/get_field/) function of ACF can be called with `$post_id` as second parameter. If you don't add that one, the `get_field` call should be inside [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Comment: I initialized it in the top of the dociument in <?php ?> tag

Comment: is there any call of `the_post()` anywhere in the document?

Comment: no there is not any call. I also have successfully isolated some sections with and worked fine, but this section did not work

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution!!!

I did not use wp_reset_query() after the last while of the section that is before this section (about section which code in the question)

when I added

```
<? endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

the problem resolved